# A mysterious folder on my computer

Tags: windows-7, file-management

There is a mysterious unidentified folder `C:/users/public/L001` where this `L001` is the folder bothering me.

It has a size of 41 GB . It's size is constantly increasing , about 0.1 GB every 3-4 days.

It contains about 1,90,591 Files currently. Even the number of files is increasing.

All the files are extension-less. All of them have the name of format `date_time`. For example : `2012-09-02_08-45-50`.

Then there are similarly names files of name : `fcdate_time`

And then there are files with name : `sddate_time`

It also contains following files (extensionless) :

1. `W0000` of size 151 MB.
2. `W0002`
3. `W0003`
4. `subcfg`

(Last three have size of few KBs)

I cannot understand what is causing this. I am not sure whether or not to delete the folder because i want to free up some space.

Comment: Please do not cross post on StackExchange sites

Comment: Start by booting without your start up applications.  Your likely infected with malware. They are not system files you should delete them. Also change the permission on the folder to prevent more files from being created

Comment: As for the duplication , I wasn't aware what was this all about . I didn't even know it was a virus or a malware . So there is know way I intended to duplicate the question. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the origin of the problem:

[Virus Profile: Generic Dropper!22BCE7D44BAF](http://home.mcafee.com/VirusInfo/VirusProfile.aspx?key=3246857#none)

You may want to install some free antivirus like [Avira](http://www.avira.com/fr/avira-free-antivirus) or [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security-essentials-download).

You can (and should) use [MalwareBytes Anti-Malware](http://www.malwarebytes.org/) to try to remove this threat.

If you already have an anti-virus (eg AVG), make sure the automatic updates of definititions files are enabled and working. Without these updates, your antivirus is useless.

Comment: I am going to go ahead and recommend using Malwarebytes.  While its clear security software should be installed, its best to use software designed to find malware, when you suspect a malware infection.

Comment: I already have AVG , should i still install Malwarebytes or something ??

Comment: updated answer in 10s :D

Comment: @iammrmehul - If you want an honest opinion, AVG is useless, I can't tell you the number of false positives and known infections it simply didn't detect.

Comment: After running several virus scanners, preferably after a restart into safe mode, you may still have the unwanted folders present in the C:\user\public folder.  After the virus scans and another reboot into normal mode, you can remove the unwanted folders.